# Error DeserializeJSON() MySQL json_object

Tags: mysql, json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting back a JSON string from a MySQL 5.7 query in ColdFusion 9.0.1. Here is my query:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(
                  JSON_OBJECT(
                    'nrtype', nrt.nrtype,
                    'number', nr.number
                    )
                )
        ) AS nrJSON
FROM    ...
```

The returned data looks like this:

```
{"nrtype": "Phone 1", "number": "12345678"},{"nrtype": "E-Mail 1", "number": "some@email.com"}
```

But as soon as I try to use `DeserializeJSON()` on it I am getting the following error:

```
JSON parsing failure at character 44:',' in {"nrtype": "Phone 1", "number": "12345678"},{"nrtype": "E-Mail 1", "number": "some@email.com"}
```

I am a little confused. What I want to get is a structure created by the `DeserializeJSON()` function.

What can I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not valid JSON as the parser is describing. If you wrap that JSON within square brackets '[' and ']' it would be valid (or at least parsable). They will make it an array of structures. Not sure how to make MySQL return the data within those brackets?

I guess you could add the brackets using ColdFusion but I would prefer to have the source do it correctly.

```
jsonhack = '[' & queryname.nrJSON & ']';
datarecord = DeserializeJSON(jsonhack);
writeDump(datarecord);
```

I created an example with your data that you can see here - [trycf.com gist](http://trycf.com/gist/4ae6bfdddc3d620244337692ce462703/acf2016?theme=monokai)

*From the comments*

The solution indeed was [to add the following to the SQL statement]:

```
CONTACT('[', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        JSON_OBJECT(...)
    ),
']')
```

Comment: Right, thank you very much. And thx for qualifying my post :D.
The solution indeed was: CONTACT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(...)), ']')

Comment: Cool glad this helped you.  And I'm glad that you found a way to add the brackets within the SQL statement instead of from the ColdFusion server.  I will add your comment to the answer so others finding this post will see it. Well done.

Answer (score -1):

If you have columns with some already containing JSON format String, try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45278722/2282880

Portion of code with **JSON_MERGE()** :

```
...
CONCAT(
    '{"elements": [',
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        JSON_MERGE(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'type',  T2.`type`,
                'data',  T2.`data`
            ),
            CONCAT('{"info": ',  T2.`info`, '}')
        )
    ),
    ']}'
) AS `elements`,
...
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16808712)

Comment: like this @kurt-van-den-branden ?